# Click listener cannot resolove to type

Tags: android

i'am beginner and i'am trying to make a simple calculator for android but he give me a syntax error

```
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    final EditText e  = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.value);
    final EditText e2 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.value2);

    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);
    Toast.makeText(this,"Welcome",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    Button welcome = (Button)findViewById(R.id.x);
    welcome.setText("push ");
    welcome.setonclickListener(new View.onclickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onclick(View v) {
            int v1 = Integer.parseInt(e.getText().toString());
            int v2 = Integer.parseInt(e2.getText().toString());
            int v3 = v1 + v2 ;
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"= " + v3, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

             return true;

         }
         });

}
```

}

http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/24/problem00.png/

Comment: this: welcome.setonclickListener(new View.onclickListener() { should be setOnClickListener and onClickListener, respectively

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `OnClickListener()`. You don't have to specify `View`. Also, make sure you use a capital 'C' in the overridden `onClick()` method. Make sure you include `import android.view.View.OnClickListener;` in your imports section. Eclipse should this for you, but if it's not or you are using Eclipse, add it manually to the top of the class. If you simply do the following, that should work for you:

```
     welcome.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            int v1 = Integer.parseInt(e.getText().toString());
            int v2 = Integer.parseInt(e2.getText().toString());
            int v3 = v1 + v2;
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "= " + v3, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            return true;

        }
    });
```

--------EDITED FOR FULL EXAMPLE--------

In your project, you have your main activity. That activity should use a layout from an XML resource. That XML resource likely looks something like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ems="10" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ems="10" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Button" />
</LinearLayout>
```

In your activity class, you have to set that resource as the content view for the activity, using `setContentView(resID)`. Say your XML file is called helloworld.xml, you would execute `setContentView(R.layout.helloworld)` in the activity's `onCreate(Bundle s)` method right after calling `super.onCreate(s)`.

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.helloworld);

}
```

Once you have set the activity's view, you can access that layout's elements (EditTexts, Buttons, etc). To do this, you'll have to create EditText and Button objects (which you were already doing in your posted code, we just have to do them elsewhere instead). Continuing with my example, you could do the following in your `onCreate(Bundle s)` function:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.helloworld);

    EditText et1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edittext1);
    EditText et2 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edittext2);
    Button but = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);

    but.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v)
            et2.setText(et1.getText().toString());
            // this will set the second EditText's text to whatever is in
            // the first EditText, but you could do anything with the value.
        }
    }
}
```

If you want to change what the button does based on a menu item selection, you have to override `onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item)` in addition to `onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu)`. `onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu)` simply creates the menu for the menu button to open. `onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item)` actually decides what to do when you select a menu item.

See the tutorial at this page for full rundown http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/menus.html, but here are their examples with some explanation. These examples are not from my example app above but from the Android Developer API pages. I strongly recommend you go over their tutorial.

All you have to do in `onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu)` is tell Android where to get the menu and to inflate that resource. This means there is an XML file called `game_menu` in the `menu` folder of the `res` folder in your project's directory.

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.game_menu, menu);
    return true;
}
```

`onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item)` is where the meat of the menu logic goes, letting you perform different tasks based on which menu item get's selected. In this example, the `game_menu` XML file mentioned in the above function has menu items called `new_game` and `help`.

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle item selection
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.new_game:
            newGame();
            return true;
        case R.id.help:
            showHelp();
            return true;
        default:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm sorry, I missed part of your question. If you want to have the user enter and manipulate values, you should put those `EditText` widgets in an Android layout XML file and set the application's Activity content view to that resource. (I'm pretty sure) you can't have anything but `MenuItem`s in an options menu. As I said before, you'll want to have the `EditText`s in a layout file. If you include manipulation buttons there, that should do the trick. I strongly recommend you read through this: http://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/building-ui.html

Comment: i'am sorry ! i didn't understand it well !!

Comment: @user1890331 Did this help or do you still need help? Mark the answer as accepted if you have what you need.

Comment: can i have your skype ? because i need to ask you about android alot !

Comment: @user1890331 If you have questions, your best bet is to post them as questions on this site. I'm rarely available for chat anyway and there are decent sized gaps in my knowledge. There are always thousands of people looking to answer questions here. You seem to be good at formulating your questions effectively so people will be much more likely to answer them. Give your account a recognizable name and I'll keep an eye out for questions from you.

Comment: when i use the code in the above of your answer he give me error in the vitrual device about stop working !

Comment: The AVD stops working or there is a Java exception? What's the error? Is it 'Unfortunately, xxx has stopped working?' or the whole AVD locks up or something else? Post the error message in the original question.

Comment: Alright, there is likely a Java exception. Can you gather a logcat from ADB and post it as an edit to your original post? If you are using Eclipse, go to the Debug perspective and run the app. The logcat will show in the LogCat pane of the Debug perspective.

Comment: Don't run it in debug mode, let the application fail so the exception is actually output to logcat.

Comment: You are having a ClassCastException caused by the fact that you are trying to create a Button object from an ImageButton resource. Make sure your XML resources and Java object type match.

Answer (score 2):

Try: `View.OnClickListener()` with a capital O and C. And the same thing with `setOnClickListener`. That should do the trick.